# Reply to Peter vs. Peter Cordes

Tags: support, bug, comments, comment-replies, display-names

In the comment section of my post, I have helpful comments from [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) and [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes). First Peter responds, then Peter Cordes. I want to reply to Peter.

> Peter: I'd question why...
>
> Peter Cordes: You don't want `-fsanitize=undefined`...
>
> me: @Peter I need uninitialized arrays because...

Unfortunately, it appears Peter Cordes was notified. This seemed like a small issue until I concluded that there is no work-around. I don't know how to notify Peter instead of Peter Cordes.

How comment replies work is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine: The duplicate-name problem is unfixable without different syntax, like ping by user-number.  This usability limitation *is* potentially fixable (note the [bug] tag), so I don't think it's a duplicate except in terms of explaining how the current algorithm works.  e.g. by preferring an exact match, even if there's a more recent prefix match.

Comment: Judging by the title, I thought this was going to be about a legal dispute about who has the right to call themselves Peter.

Comment: Perhaps one workaround would be implementing additional matching based on user id, e.g. @user4706785.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if multiple people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John. (Use the next rule to differentiate. Note that in this case, the autocomplete may show multiple listings for the same username, but there's no difference in selecting any one of those.)

Note that, in this case the "next rule" is not helpful for this situation.

So if the longer name matches the shorter name in all of the shorter names characters then you won't be able to match the shorter name unless one of the following happens...

1. the shorter name comments again so that user has the more recent comment
2. the longer name's comments that make it more recent are deleted